# Why are integration tests not executed by default in a maven build (install)?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-failsafe-plugin

To my understanding, by default (that means without any explicit configuration of the failsafe plugin), maven should run integration tests when the goal "install" is executed. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference.

Anyway, it seems to do not so. So, possibly I am misunderstanding something.

I made up a minimal test project with a JUnit test class org.example.ExampleIT in src/test/java and the following POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>mvn-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The build (mvn install) is succesful, but failsafe is not executed. See the following log excerpt:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ mvn-project ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mvn-project ---
(...)
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ mvn-project
(...)
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: mvn clean verify?

Comment: You didn't read carefully document you linked. **A Build Lifecycle is Made Up of Phases** : `verify - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met`

Comment: I am talking about mvn install here, which should include the integration-test phase (install comes after verify), but the result is same for verify.

Comment: nope, install goal invokes only unit test (via surefire by default).

Comment: @rkosegi: How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: By years of experience and of course, by reading docs

Comment: From the ref: "The following lists all build phases of the default, clean and site lifecycles, which are executed in the order given up to the point of the one specified."

Comment: Before making wrong assumption, run your maven with "-X"  argument which will gives you idea about which goal and plugins are being invoked. Btw, where the hell is mention that `install` goal invokes `integration-tests` ?

Comment: Anyway, even explicitely invoking maven with the goal "integration-test" does not change the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135737/discussion-between-gustave-and-rkosegi).

Comment: @rkosegi Invoking the _install_ phase automatically invokes the _verify_ phase. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html.

Plugins are bound to lifecycles phases by a "Plugin Binding". Those bindings are specific to the packaging.

The default bindings are defined in META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml in maven core. The default binding for jar packaging does not provide any plugin binding for the integration-test phase (see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging), for that reason the binding of the failsafe plugin to the integration-test and verify phases must be configured manually (see answer from JF Meier).

The plugin must not only be bound to the integration-test phase, but to the verify phase, too. Otherwise the tests are executed, but the build does not fail if some integration test fails.

Answer (score 2):

You should actually execute the plugin by

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You can find more information on:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html

Comment: This will not bind failsafe to `install` phase unless you add `<phase>test</phase>` into config (or similar)

Comment: @JF Meier: Yep, thanks! But why is it not bound to the integration-test phase by default like surefire is bound to test?

Comment: @Gustave Don't know but I guess that integration tests are not needed in every build.